# Binding of private attributes: nqp::bindattr vs :=

Tags: raku, nqp

I'm trying to find how the binding operation works on attributes and what makes it so different from `nqp::bindattr`. Consider the following example:

```
 class Foo {
     has @!foo;

     submethod TWEAK {
         my $fval = [<a b c>];
         use nqp;
         nqp::bindattr( nqp::decont(self), $?CLASS, '@!foo',
         #@!foo :=
             Proxy.new(
                 FETCH => -> $ { $fval },
                 STORE => -> $, $v { $fval = $v }
             )
         );
     }

     method check {
         say @!foo.perl;
     }
 }

 my $inst = Foo.new;
 $inst.check;
```

It prints:

> `$["a", "b", "c"]`

Replacing `nqp::bindattr` with the binding operator from the comment gives correct output:

> `["a", "b", "c"]`

Similarly, if `foo` is a public attribute and accessor is used the output would be correct too due to deconterisation taking place within the accessor.

I use similar code in my `AttrX::Mooish` module where use of `:=` would overcomplicate the implementation. So far, `nqp::bindattr` did the good job for me until the above problem arised.

I tried tracing down Rakudo's internals looking for `:=` implementation but without any success so far. I would ask here either for an advise as to how to simulate the operator or where in the source to look for its implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before I dig into the answer: most things in this post are implementation-defined, and the implementation is free to define them differently in the future.

To find out what something (naively) compiles into under Rakudo Perl 6, use the `--target=ast` option (`perl6 --target=ast foo.p6`). For example, the bind in:

```
class C {
    has $!a;
    submethod BUILD() {
        my $x = [1,2,3];
        $!a := $x
    }
}
```

Comes out as:

```
                              - QAST::Op(bind)  :statement_id<7>
                                - QAST::Var(attribute $!a) <wanted> $!a
                                  - QAST::Var(lexical self) 
                                  - QAST::WVal(C) 
                                - QAST::Var(lexical $x)  $x
```

While switching it for `@!a` like here:

```
class C {
    has @!a;
    submethod BUILD() {
        my $x = [1,2,3];
        @!a := $x
    }
}
```

Comes out as:

```
                              - QAST::Op(bind)  :statement_id<7>
                                - QAST::Var(attribute @!a) <wanted> @!a
                                  - QAST::Var(lexical self) 
                                  - QAST::WVal(C) 
                                - QAST::Op(p6bindassert) 
                                  - QAST::Op(decont) 
                                    - QAST::Var(lexical $x)  $x
                                  - QAST::WVal(Positional)
```

The `decont` instruction is the big difference here, and it will take the contents of the `Proxy` by calling its `FETCH`, thus why the containerization is gone. Thus, you can replicate the behavior by inserting `nqp::decont` around the `Proxy`, although that rather begs the question of what the `Proxy` is doing there if the correct answer is obtained without it!

Both `:=` and `=` are compiled using case analysis (namely, by looking at what is on the left hand side). `:=` only works for a limited range of simple expressions on the left; it is a decidedly low-level operator. By contrast, `=` falls back to a `sub` call if the case analysis doesn't come up with a more efficient form to emit, though in most cases it manages something better.

The case analysis for `:=` inserts a `decont` when the target is a lexical or attribute with sigil `@` or `%`, since - at a Perl 6 level - having an item bound to an `@` or `%` makes no sense. Using `nqp::bindattr` is going a level below Perl 6 semantics, and so it's *possible* to end up with the `Proxy` bound directly there using that. However, it also violates expectations elsewhere. Don't expect that to go well (but it seems you don't want to do that anyway.)

Comment: I have seen some bits of QAST building in the source but `--target` povides more clear view. Note also that my knowelge of compiler internals is very basic and I might be asking silly questions. But for now I have discovered that `:=` doesn't work the way I thought it would. It deconts instantly thus binding not to a `Proxy` instance but to what `FETCH` returns at the moment when binding happens. Of course, same happens with decont-wrapped `Proxy` as `bindattr` parameter.

Comment: BTW,  prior to asking here I was trying to strip off container of `FETCH` return with both `nqp::decont` and `<>`. But neither works, `@!foo` returns scalar container.

Comment: This could be useful. Further investigation revealed that direct call to `Proxy`'s `FETCH` returns validly decontainerised value: `@!foo.VAR.^find_method('FETCH')(@!foo).perl` prints `["a", "b", "c"]` as expected from what I see in _BOOTSTRAP.nqp_ code. It looks more and more like a bug.

Comment: There's a deliberately retained bug around `Proxy` handling and return value processing. We didn't properly `decont` `Proxy` on `return`. I fixed it, but the fix then broke a bunch of ecosystem modules because folks hadn't put the required `is rw` on routines. So the fix was backed out to allow some more time for modules to get fixed up.

Comment: Sounds somewhat like "it won't be fixed". But at least I now know what to write in the documentation. Thanks Jonathan!

Comment: We intend to put the fix back; we can't wait for every module to be patched (or even to merge a PR that we send), but we can give a couple of monthly release's grace.